# jquery .length returning wrong value when emoji's are used

Tags: jquery, utf-8, utf-16, utf

I need to count the length of a string with jquery.

`$(element).text().length` is not returning the amount of characters I would like.

😂 text 😷

The above string is returning 10 characters but I would like it to return 8 characters.

I did some research and apparently it is because the 2 emoji's are using UTF16 but I am unsure on how to fix it.

Can anybody help?

Comment: It's not just jQuery. [JavaScript has a Unicode problem](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode).

Comment: BTW, jQuery.length does not have anything to do with strings. I presume you post the wrong example :-?

Comment: Hi Alvaro, I have edited my question. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @DanielOrmerod That's right. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I found my answer by following the instructions in the duplicate answer. Thank you for all your help.